# change to another screen after login is successful

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, safari-app-extension

The use case of the app I am developing is I will have login view at the initial. When user logs in with valid credentials, the user should see another view saying welcome user. I am totally beginner and I don't know much more about xcode. I see the screen navigation from storyboard but I have already done many things in xib.

Here is what I have done

**SafariExtensionViewController.swift**

```
import SafariServices

class SafariExtensionViewController: SFSafariExtensionViewController {


    @IBOutlet weak var passwordMessage: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var emailMessage: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var message: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var email: NSTextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var password: NSSecureTextField!
    static let shared = SafariExtensionViewController()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 300, height: 250)
        message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
    }


    @IBAction func userLogin(_ sender: Any) {
        let providedEmailAddress = email.stringValue
        let providedPassword = password.stringValue
        let isEmailAddressValid = isValidEmailAddress(emailAddressString: providedEmailAddress)
        self.message.stringValue = ""
        emailMessage.stringValue = ""
        passwordMessage.stringValue = ""
        if isEmailAddressValid && providedPassword.count > 0 {
            // api call is done here
            // when success should show another screen
        } else {
            emailMessage.textColor = NSColor.red
            emailMessage.stringValue = "Invalid Email"
        }
    }    
}
```

here is the screenshot of xib.

[image]

Technology used

swift 4

xcode 9

not IOS its mainly for app extension

UPDATE

I am not using storyboard and also it's not IOS. I am using xib and from macos project I am trying to develop app extension which will be shown in browser as an extension.

Comment: it has used storyboard and also its IOS.

Comment: did you figure out how to approach this problem? were you able to use a storyboard?

Comment: we just went with chrome extension so we did not work on it after that.

Comment: I ended up using this approach. It seems like you cannot use storyboards or swift ui for safari extensions. it's kind of hacky, but it got the job done.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of time left from question posted, but it can be helpful for others as me (I'm porting safari legacy extension to safari app extension) and find the way with use of `NSTabView` with tabless style:

[image]

The use is:

[image]

Ensure to add `NSObject` in your storyboard from the Library:

[image]

And connect with the tabview from Outlet:

[image]

I'm rather newbie in Cocoa and Swift and if anyone knows more beautiful solution for routing, please share it with others!